# What is the Proper Way To Configure a Multi Tenancy with Shared Schema in EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, multi-tenant

I'm working on designing a multi-tenant application. I have a Tenant entity, User entity, and multiple other entities that have a TenantId property.

I started adding child references to my Tenant entity, but looking at other code examples leads me to believe that this isn't the "correct" way to get the child entities to properly register the TenantId foreign key. However, if I don't add the child collections to my Tenant entity, the migrations don't register the TenantId foreign key to the children.

What is the correct (or suggested) way to manage these relationships in a Shared Schema Multi-Tenant pattern?

For example, suppose I have a Tenant with Users that all have access to Taxis, Garages, and Zones within their Tenant.

**Note: I'm using a base class in my real code, but decided that would complicate the example so I intentionally spelled everything out.**

```
public class Tenant
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

    // Should the below properties be left out?
    public ICollection<Taxi> Taxis { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Garage> Garages { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Zone> Zones { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long TenantId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class Taxi
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long TenantId { get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set; }
}

public class Garage
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long TenantId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Zone
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long TenantId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you will have a Tenant as a virtual property in the models like the one given below,

```
public class User
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long TenantId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual Tenant TenantDetails {get;set;}
}
```

you might be required to get all the dependent entity written under a tenant.

However, if that is not the case, you don't have to use the dependent entity as the child under the Tenant Entity. Normally, we consider tenant to be a metadata of the application or a higher level domain object. The remaining entities like the business objects can have a **Tenant** property to identify the tenant detail for the record, but IMHO, the vice-versa is not required on a realtime use rather from an EF modelling standpoint.